# WPF Ribbon Samples

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I installed WPF Ribbon 2010, and the WPF Ribbon Samples.

But where are the WPF Ribbon Samples installed?

How do I open, for example, RibbonWindow Wordpad Sample?

Comment: You should find it in Program Files. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Ribbon for WPF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to find it in the `Program Files`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Ribbon for WPF`

or

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Ribbon for WPF`

Note: To get the samples, you should have downloaded the file `Microsoft Ribbon for WPF Source and Samples.msi`. The download link is given below.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=11877